# Orphan in a dystopia, food is served in edible containers

Tags: story-identification

After much thinking, I think this may be cyberpunk. (I may be wrong)
In the beginning of the novel, the protagonist, an orphan, I think. He is in an institution, sleeps in tiny cell. Food is served on cardboard-like trays? that are also edible. At some point, he eats something with mold on it, on purpose, against infection or something.

He is rescued? pretty soon, and then there is rooftop running, I think.

Will edit if I manage to think of more details.

Comment: When did you read this, in what form, and what language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[The Supernaturalist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Supernaturalist)* by Eoin Colfer

> The Supernaturalist takes place in Satellite City, a large city in an unspecified location in the Northern Hemisphere, in the third millennium. Much of Satellite City is controlled by the Satellite, owned by Myishi Corporation. By the time of the novel, however, the Satellite is losing links to the surface, causing disasters that range from mild to catastrophic.
>
> The book opens with an introduction to Cosmo Hill, an orphan at the Clarissa Frayne Institute for Parentally Challenged Boys. At the Institute, the boys are used as human guinea pigs for various products. However, on a trip back from a record company, the truck transporting them crashes. Cosmo and a friend, Francis (aka "Ziplock") manage to escape the wreckage, but are pursued by a warden from the Institute. The chase takes them to the rooftops, where Cosmo and Ziplock fall into a wrecked generator. Ziplock is electrocuted but Cosmo survives, albeit with multiple critical injuries, including several broken bones and a heart which begins to shut down. He begins seeing small blue creatures around him. When one lands on his chest and begins sucking his life out, three figures appear out of nowhere and kill the creature. Although the teens want to leave him, Cosmo begs them to take him with them, pleading to not be left to be eaten by the strange blue beings. The group labels him a "Spotter" and, after some argument, take him with them before he passes out....

[This excerpt from Google Books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Supernaturalist/30ZuZjVP7V0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22the%20supernaturalist%22%20mold&pg=PA43&printsec=frontcover) mentions the mold.

> Cosmo closed his eyes, remembering the institute. "Those Komposite darts were tested at Clarissa Frayne. I remember. The green-and-white ones were the worst. We called them Creepers. Guys were sick for house, even after they got the antidote. The institute's plumbing got all backed up. One guy found a cure, though. He ate a moldy sandwich, and felt better. It wasn't the bread, it was --"

And yes, the trays were edible.

> ... The trays and water bottles were luminous, and also edible, which meant the orphans could eat after lights-out, saving the management a few dinars...

Comment: ^_^ It's become one of my go-tos when someone mentions an orphan in a sci-fi scenario.

Comment: If so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/77471/sci-fi-book-blue-critters-than-only-some-people-can-see-kids-fight-the-critter, although you can see this comes up fairly often, so you're in good company.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87276/whats-the-name-of-a-book-about-the-adventures-of-a-group-of-orphans?noredirect=1&lq=1 is actually a pretty direct match in terms of provided details. Both the edible trays and eating the moldy bread are mentioned.

Comment: Thanks! Funny thing. When I googled for keywords, The Supernaturalist did come up, but I totally ignored it. This was exactly what I was looking for. Now I'm going to read the wiki article, because I totally don't remember this book...